# How do I get a list of files from a folder using 'contains'

Tags: android

I am trying to get a list of files from an online folder using the following:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='BB0CHANGEDIDF5waGdzbU12345'+in+parents&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

This will return all the files in the folder. How do I code the string so I can search using 'contains'? I've tried many ways (single quotes, double quotes, +, etc) and I still receive ALL the files in the folder - or none at all.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to URL encode the search string to convert into HTML entities. So for example a string like:

```
...?q=name contains 'searchstring'...
```

becomes

```
...?q=name+contains+%27searchstring%27....
```

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters#examples